# "Ain't even in third yet." What does it mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

In the movie Bonnie and Clyde (2013), Clyde just escapes from prison. He jumps in the car that Bonnie has prepared and says "Ain't even in third yet."

> Clyde: **Ain't even in third yet.**
>
> Bonnie: I got your suit in the back. Even got us a place to go.

What does Clyde mean here? What is third in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Third**

is a reference to *third gear* on manual transmission car.

He is saying they are not going fast yet since most of the speed comes when in 3rd or 4th gear.